Idea applicability size greater than family size and idea sharing
I wonder whether there are words on publications in economics that describe and explore the following relationship:

Idea applicability size greater than family size and idea or idea gist sharing our tendency to share idea on the web, in books, at conferences or vocal performances.

I was thinking this, because I was thinking that done families have ideas and keep the idea within the family for self sustainability, while, other ideas, may have more applicability (or, business, generation, potential), and may be more suitable for sharing, while other ideas may be downright straightforward business idea donations for people to use and implement outside, of, their, immediate family.
People, may, have an expanded/expansive, virtual family.
Order ideas, may be, to be implemented, by others, in support, of one's own, or others', families.
Other ideas, may be stuff that goes towards helping others, even if one's own family can't benefit (besides, being happy for helping), from them.
I was wondering, how, to make sense, expand, or explore, on these relationships.
I was thinking, they, thinking, about, these ideas categories (like any type of idea thinking in economics), may help us, decide, what kind of ideas we need to develop according to where the need arises most.
Thanks.

It would be helpful to give concrete examples of the ideas of different scopes you are talking about. Currently you question is very confusing.
